# how to use aws cli filters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I need to be able to get the public IP's of all AWS EC2 instances in all of our environments.

The basic command goes like this:

```
    aws ec2 describe-addresses --profile=company-lab_us-east-1
ADDRESSES       eipalloc-blah      eipassoc-blah       vpc     i-blah      eni-blah 486469900423       xxx.xxx.xxx.xx xx.xx.xx.xxx  ## <-- last set of x's is the public IP
```

I'm trying to filter the output so that just the public IP is shown:

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --profile=company-lab_us-east-1 --filters "Name=public-ip-address"

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeAddresses operation: The filter 'public-ip-address' is invalid
```

I'd like to take the output of the filtered command and put it into a variable in a bash script. So that I can come up with a report of all the IP addresses in all of our AWS environments.

Comment: Did you try this aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-b78a096f | grep PublicIpAddress | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed 's/[",]//g'

Comment: no, because I have to get a list of public ip's for all instances, and there are hundreds of them. Hard coding them isn't practical in this case. Also, PublicIpAddress doesn't exist in the original command output. So you can't grep for it. Thanks

Comment: Ok try this one aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[PublicIpAddress,InstanceId]"

Comment: Pretty cool! But now I'm getting output like this: None    i-8b6d98d8
None    i-6c46ff41
None    i-6822a487
None    i-f230b61d
52.70.102.70    i-297b659e. And I need ONLY the public IP.. any ideas? I tried adjusting the command but no luck

Comment: I've tried this and a couple other variations: aws ec2 describe-instances --query "[PublicIpAddress]" --profile=company-nonprod_us-east-1
None

Comment: Ok None means those instances do not have a public IP what was the out put of  aws ec2 describe-instances --query "[PublicIpAddress]" --profile=company-nonprod_us-east-1

Comment: Try this aws ec2 describe-instances --query "[PublicIpAddress]"

Comment: hmm... no luck yet
` aws ec2 describe-instances --query "[PublicIpAddress]" --profile=kpmg-prod_us-east-1
None`

Comment: Ok Last :) Try this aws ec2 describe-instances --output table   --query '[0].Value, PublicIpAddress]'

Comment: Sorry no luck yet. `aws ec2 describe-instances --output table --query '[0].Value, PublicIpAddress]'  --profile=kpmg-prod_us-east-1

Bad value for --query '[0].Value,: Bad jmespath expression: Unclosed ' delimiter:
'[0].Value,
^` . Thanks for trying! :)

Comment: One more I found ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress" --output text

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

The `--filters` option does not filter the information that is displayed. Instead, `--filters` is applied to the list of instances before the information is returned. So for example, the `public-ip-address` filter means to "describe my addresses but only the one with this public IP address."

You will have to describe all and parse the public IP addresses from the output using the tool(s) of your choice.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm getting close. I tried this:  aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "[public-ip-address]"  --profile=kpmg-nonprod_us-east-1

No JSON object could be decoded

But I'm getting back the above error.

Comment: `aws ec2 describe-addresses | jq '.Addresses[] .PublicIp'` will list your public IP addresses. Maybe you can build off that.

Answer (score 0):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress'
```

Answer (score 0):

*I need to be able to get the public IP's of all AWS EC2 instances in all of our environments*

while the other answers provide correct statement I would complete and assume that *all of our environments* can also refer to multi region settings.

I would run the following query

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --output text |\
cut -f 3 | \
xargs -I {} aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Placement.AvailabilityZone, State.Name, InstanceId, PublicIpAddress]' \
    --output text \
    --region {}
```

The advantage here is that the first part of the command will return all the available regions so it will return the following information for *all* your environment

- The availability zone (your region)
- the state if the instance is running or not
- the Id of the instance
- finally the public IP of your instance